# Âncora para as tabs do Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, estou fazendo um painel de perguntas e respostas, no qual uso as tabs do bootstrap para melhor organizar as perguntas. Eu queria que cada vez que o usuário respondesse um pergunta, pulasse para a próxima, mas não consigo fazer isso como uma âncora, eu procurei na internet, mas só achei com URL.

Segue uma foto:
 [image: Imagem do sistema]

E quando a pessoa clicar em finalizar eu mando um confirm perguntando se ele tem certeza que deseja finalizar. E queria que se o usuário não confirmasse, voltasse para a tab que ele estava, mas caso contrário, ele fosse para a tab "finalizar". Eu queria só a forma de criar essa âncora para as tabs sem ter a necessidade do usuário clicar em cada uma...

Quem puder ajudar, agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar a aba via JS você pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
$('#id_tab').tab('show');
```

Caso queira que exiba o hash na URL ao mudar as abas você pode adicionar o seguinte função em seu arquivo JS:

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

 $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop() || $('html').scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
  });
});
```

---

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131273/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-url-doesnt-change

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas eu não sei o que está acontecendo, porque o $('#id_tab').tab('show'); não está funcionando...

Comment: Como você está fazendo o gatilho para abrir a tab? 

Se você estiver usando `$("#id_element").click(function(){})`, é importante lembrar que isso não irá funcionar para elementos dinâmicos, então você teria que usar `$(document).on( 'click' , '#id_event', function(){});`. Em todo caso seria melhor se postasse o código para que possamos ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Quando a pessoa clica em finalizar, eu executo uma função para confirmar se ela quer mesmo finalizar. Uso um confirm para isso. Se for true, eu quero que vá para a aba de finalizar, se não for, quero que volte para a pergunta número 1.

Answer (score 0):

Segue os códigos:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" id="botaoFinalizar" onclick="confirmarEnvioQuestionario();">Finalizar</a></li>
```

Esse ai de cima é o do Botão para finalizar (eu não coloquei o href="#finalizar" pois ele faz isso depois da função e buga tudo).

```
<li <?php echo ($r == 1) ? "class='active'" : "" ?>><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pergunta-<?php echo $r ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>
```

Aqui no caso é o loop que eu faço para mostrar as perguntas, mas até aqui não tem problema, ele funciona normal.O problema é que não faz a âncora e também não aparece nada no console.

```
function confirmarEnvioQuestionario(){
//VALIDA PARA VER SE PREENCHEU TODOS OS CAMPOS
//SE SIM, PEDE PARA CONFIRMAR
if(validaCampos()){
    var c = confirm("Tem certeza que quer finalizar o questionário?");
}
else{
    alert("Responda todas as questões primeiro!");
    return false;
}
if(c == true){
    $('#finalizar').tab('show');
    carregaResultadoQuestionario();
}
else{
    $('#pergunta-1').tab('show');
}
```

}

E antes de pergunte, sim, todas as funções que estão nessa fnção estão funcionando e as tabs estão com os id's correspondentes.

Comment: Tente remover o ` data-toggle="tab"` do elemento `<a>` no botão de finalizar, e coloque um `href="#"`.

Comment: Creio que o problema não seja com o botão, tentei do jeito qe você falou mas continua sem fncionar.